# How do I Create a Custom Template File in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm new to Wordpress and PHP so be gentle. I've searched the Wordpress documentation but can't find an answer to this.

I need to create a section of HTML (and/or PHP) to use in multiple page templates. I'm not exactly sure what this is called, but I want it to act the same as the built-in Wordpress Template Files like header, sidebar, footer etc...

To be clear, this is different than creating my own custom Page Template.

The usage would be something like this:

```
// index.php
<?php get_header(); ?>
// Some index page content
<?php get_customrecentcontentsection(); ?>
// Some more index page content
<?php get_footer(); ?>


// customrecentcontentsection.php
<div>
// Some Wordpress post query with some HTML php
</div>
```

I would then use `<?php get_customrecentcontentsection(); ?>` at the end of the Post Template or anywhere else I see fit.

Currently, I have duplicate code in index.php and post.php which I'm trying to get rid of.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, **to use it as a function** you need to **create it as a function** in your template's functions.php page.

Then you can create a new .php file inside your theme, maybe in a folder called **templates**. You name it so you can call the file from the function you've just created:

```
function get_customrecentcontentsection(){
    require('templates/yourSharedFile.php');
}
```

The straight way is to print directly the content.

```
function get_customrecentcontentsection(){
    print 'your awesome content';
}
```

I whould suggest you to download a couple or three of reputated templates to see how the nice Wordpress themers handle with that. Also Google for some best practices in Wordpress theming.

It's not that hard, reading a couple of articles you will be there!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put some comment like on the top of your file :

```
/*
Template Name: My Template
*/
```

You can find more informations here : [How to create a custom template](http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/)